# How to build a rocket?

Tags: aerodynamics, rocket

I am trying to build a rocket (a small one for scientific purposes) for the very first time, I've never tried to do that before, and I can say I have almost little to no knowledge about this, so I am seeking some kind of starting kit, besides the YouTube videos that I watched dozens of it to proceed this crazy idea, so where should I look? and where do I start?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE. This question is probably too broad to be answered well in a single post, and rocketry isn't really on-topic on this forum, so it's likely that your question will be closed. For a place to get started, though, check out [Estes model rockets](https://estesrockets.com/).

Comment: If you've watched dozens of Youtube videos you've probably watched videos of people that make their own motors, their own rockets etc. **Do not**, I repeat: **do not** do that as your first project (or 2nd, or 3rd ...). Start with model rockets, learn, work your way up, and ask questions in [more suitable forums](https://www.rocketryforum.com) Also, depending on where you live, it may be very difficult or impossible to get model rocket motors and also be illegal to fly them.

Comment: @RalphJ You're probably right, I think I might close it myself, but before I do that, if you have anything you would like to share besides "Estes model rockets", I would appreciate it, like I said I have little to no knowledge so I need to get the theoretical part first before getting to the making of it.

Comment: @Raketenolli In addition to suitable forums, are there any books I could use? I want to read more about it before really getting into doing it because YouTube was a bad place to start with, I want to read more about the perfect design, the perfect materials, and the perfect motors...etc

Comment: Try the book by G. Harry Stine titled "The Handbook of Model Rocketry." It's a must-read for beginners.

Comment: There is no such thing as the perfect rocket. I think the best book to get started is "Make: Rockets" by Mike Westerfield.

Answer (score 1):

You start by buying yourself a small DIY rocket kit made by the Estes Corporation, as sold in hobby shops all across this broad and prosperous land of ours. Then you work your way up from the beginner-level kits to the more complex multi-stage kits with bigger motors in them. From there you join a model rocketry club and learn how to construct the whole rocket from scratch without blowing yourself up.